# dev express grid in mvc c# inline edit not expanding

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, devexpress

I am trying to get the inline editing using the dev express grid. I have follows the example as said in 
http://mvc.devexpress.com/GridView/InlineEditingWithTemplate
and also confirmed it by looking at http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dKCFLyvf32Y this link. 
code for my controller is as follows:

```
[ValidateInput(false)]
        public ActionResult InlineEditingWithTemplatePartial()
        {
            int siteID = (int)Session["siteID"];
            return PartialView("InlineEditingWithTemplatePartial", employeeRepo.GetAllEmployeesForSite(siteID));
        }

        [HttpPost, ValidateInput(false)]
        public ActionResult InlineEditingWithTemplateAddNewPartial([ModelBinder(typeof(DevExpressEditorsBinder))] Employee employee)
        {
            int siteID = 0;
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                try
                {
                    siteID = (int)Session["siteID"];
                    //employee.InsertProduct(employee);
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    ViewData["EditError"] = e.Message;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                ViewData["EditError"] = "Please, correct all errors.";
                ViewData["EmployeeDetail"] = employee;
            }
            return PartialView("InlineEditingWithTemplatePartial", employeeRepo.GetAllEmployeesForSite(siteID));
        }

        [HttpPost, ValidateInput(false)]
        public ActionResult InlineEditingWithTemplateUpdatePartial([ModelBinder(typeof(DevExpressEditorsBinder))] Employee employee)
        {
            int siteID = 0;
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                try
                {
                    siteID = (int)Session["siteID"];
                    employeeRepo.SaveEmployee(employee);
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    ViewData["EditError"] = e.Message;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                ViewData["EditError"] = "Please, correct all errors.";
                ViewData["EnployeeDetail"] = employee;
            }

            return PartialView("InlineEditingWithTemplatePartial", employeeRepo.GetAllEmployeesForSite(siteID));
        }

        [HttpPost, ValidateInput(false)]
        public ActionResult InlineEditingWithTemplateDeletePartial(Employee employee)
        {
            int siteID = 0;
            if (employee!=null)
            {
                try
                {
                    siteID = (int)Session["siteID"];
                    employeeRepo.DeleteEmployee(employee);
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    ViewData["EditError"] = e.Message;
                }
            }
            return PartialView("InlineEditingWithTemplatePartial", employeeRepo.GetAllEmployeesForSite(siteID));
        }
```

and code for the view is:

```
@using MyProject6.Data.Models;
@using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
@using DevExpress.Web.Mvc.UI;
@using DevExpress.Web.ASPxEditors;
@using DevExpress.Web.Mvc;
@using DevExpress.Web.ASPxGridView;

@{
    var grid = Html.DevExpress().GridView(
        settings =>
        {
            settings.Name = "gvEmployeeEditing"; 
            settings.KeyFieldName = "EmployeeID";

            settings.CallbackRouteValues = new { Controller = "Home", Action = "InlineEditingWithTemplatePartial" };
            settings.ClientSideEvents.BeginCallback = "function(s,e){e.customArgs['id'] = '" + ViewContext.RouteData.Values["EmployeeID"] + "'}";

            settings.SettingsEditing.AddNewRowRouteValues = new { Controller = "Home", Action = "" };    //InlineEditingUpdatePartial
            settings.SettingsEditing.UpdateRowRouteValues = new { Controller = "Home", Action = "InlineEditingWithTemplateUpdatePartial"};
            settings.SettingsEditing.DeleteRowRouteValues = new { Controller = "Home", Action = "" };    //InlineEditingUpdatePartial

            settings.SettingsEditing.Mode = GridViewEditingMode.EditFormAndDisplayRow;
            settings.SettingsBehavior.ConfirmDelete = true;

            settings.CommandColumn.Visible = true;
            settings.CommandColumn.NewButton.Visible = true;
            settings.CommandColumn.DeleteButton.Visible = true;
            settings.CommandColumn.EditButton.Visible = true;

            settings.Columns.Add("EmployeeID");
            settings.Columns.Add("EmployeeCode");
            settings.Columns.Add("FirstName");
            settings.Columns.Add("LastName").PropertiesEdit.DisplayFormatString = "c";
            settings.Columns.Add("DefaultRoleTitle");

            settings.SetEditFormTemplateContent(c => {
                var employee = ViewData["EditableEmployeeDetail"] != null ? ViewData["EditableEmployeeDetail"] : c.DataItem;
                ViewContext.Writer.Write(
                    "<div class=\"edit_form\">" +
                    "<div class=\"line\">"
                );
                    Html.DevExpress().Label(
                        edtSettings => {
                            edtSettings.ControlStyle.CssClass = "label";
                            edtSettings.Text = "Employee Code";
                            edtSettings.AssociatedControlName = "EmployeeCode";
                        }
                    )
                    .Render();
                    Html.DevExpress().TextBox(
                        edtSettings => {
                            edtSettings.Name = "EmployeeCode";
                            edtSettings.ControlStyle.CssClass = "editor";
                            edtSettings.ShowModelErrors = true;
                        }
                    )
                    .Bind(DataBinder.Eval(employee, "EmployeeCode"))
                    .Render();

                ViewContext.Writer.Write(
                    "</div>" +
                    "<div class=\"line\">"
                );
                    Html.DevExpress().Label(
                        edtSettings => {
                            edtSettings.ControlStyle.CssClass = "label";
                            edtSettings.Text = "First Name:";
                            edtSettings.AssociatedControlName = "FirstName";
                        }
                    )
                    .Render();

                    Html.DevExpress().TextBox(
                    edtSettings =>
                    {
                        edtSettings.Name = "FirstName";
                        edtSettings.ControlStyle.CssClass = "editor";
                        edtSettings.Text = "First Name";
                        edtSettings.ShowModelErrors = true;
                    }
                    ).Bind(DataBinder.Eval(employee, "FirstName"))
                    .Render();

                ViewContext.Writer.Write(
                    "</div>" +
                    "<div class=\"line\">"
                );
                    Html.DevExpress().Label(
                        edtSettings => {
                            edtSettings.ControlStyle.CssClass = "label";
                            edtSettings.Text = "Last Name:";
                            edtSettings.AssociatedControlName = "LastName";
                        }
                    )
                    .Render();
                    Html.DevExpress().TextBox(
                        edtSettings => {
                            edtSettings.Name = "LastName";
                            edtSettings.ControlStyle.CssClass = "editor";
                            edtSettings.ShowModelErrors = true;
                        }
                    )
                    .Bind(DataBinder.Eval(employee, "LastName"))
                    .Render();
                ViewContext.Writer.Write(
                    "</div>" +
                    "<div class=\"line\">"
                );
                Html.DevExpress().Label(
                    edtSettings =>
                    {
                        edtSettings.ControlStyle.CssClass = "label";
                    }
                )
                .Render();
                Html.DevExpress().Button(
                    btnSettings =>
                    {
                        btnSettings.Name = "btnUpdate";
                        btnSettings.ControlStyle.CssClass = "button";
                        btnSettings.Text = "Update";
                        btnSettings.ClientSideEvents.Click = "function(s, e){ gvEmployeeEditing.UpdateEdit(); }";
                    }
                )
                .Render();
                Html.DevExpress().Button(
                    btnSettings =>
                    {
                        btnSettings.Name = "btnCancel";
                        btnSettings.ControlStyle.CssClass = "button";
                        btnSettings.Text = "Cancel";
                        btnSettings.ClientSideEvents.Click = "function(s, e){ gvEmployeeEditing.CancelEdit(); }";
                    }
                )
                .Render();
                ViewContext.Writer.Write(
                    "</div></div>"
                );
            });

            settings.PreRender = (sender, e) =>
            {
                MVCxGridView gridView = (MVCxGridView)sender;
            };


        });

    if(ViewData["EditError"] != null){
        grid.SetEditErrorText((string)ViewData["EditError"]);
    }
}

@grid.Bind(Model).GetHtml()
```

This view is the partial view that I call from an index View of the Home Controller. 
I tried to debug it and the code for inline editing is just not entered. Looks like its not calling back anything. 
I am not sure what Im missing here and Ive spent the last two days looking for a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can use a solution from the [E3998](http://www.devexpress.com/example=E3998) example.

If you have any troubles with the implementation, you can contact DX guys directly.